# What's wrong with my cronjob?

Tags: shell-script, cron, startup

I want to run a script on startup that establishes a GRE tunnel. 
The script works fine if I just run `/root/tunnel.sh` after rebooting, it runs and establishes the tunnel. 
Below are the contents of my crontab -e for root user on my machine.

```
@reboot sleep 15; /root/tunnel.sh
```

Am I missing something?

I'm running CentOS 7 if that helps.

Comment: Start by adding logging like this 
@reboot sleep 15; /root/tunnel.sh >> /tmp/some.log 2>&1
reading that log  will give you a clue

Comment: does /root/tunnel.sh rely on any shell variables (or activities) performed by your login shell? Is the correct she-bang line at the top of it?

Comment: You're not mentioning what happens when the cronjob runs. Do you get an email with any error messages from the cron daemon?

Comment: @Tagwint I made it log the action and the log tell me `/root/tunnel.sh: line 2: ip: command not found`
Does this just mean I'm not waiting it long enough or what? Since the commands work fine if I execute the script from the bash terminal or if I paste all the commands from it one by one

Comment: @JeffSchaller I didn't have the she-bang on the top of the script but I added it now and did what Tagwint told me to do to log the output of the script. since it outputs what I posted in the above comment I presume it's not a problem with variables or activities done by the shell.

Comment: Tangentially related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232789/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /root/tunnel.sh: line 2: ip: command not found

Your root login profile (one of ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile) is setting `$PATH` to include /usr/sbin, while your (non-login) script is *not* setting `$PATH` to include /usr/sbin.

Either expand `$PATH` in your script or use full paths to programs that are in /usr/sbin.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
```

or

```
/usr/sbin/ip ...
```

Comment: I have another @reboot cronjob for a script, but unfortunately that doesn't work either. The script looks like this: 
    
`#!/bin/sh
cd /home/mc/mc/
while true
do
   java -Xms10G -Xmx10G -jar spigot.jar
   echo done
   sleep 3
done` 

(sorry for it not being properly formatted the comments don't seem to support the code block formatting)

And the log I set up for it just shows: `Must be connected to a terminal.`

Comment: Sounds like it might be a [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!