# ufw "command not found"- but as the root user!

Tags: bash, debian, path, ufw

My Debian 11 VPS is running now for about 2 weeks- and today I just wanted to analyse, why my traffic is ~70GiB (counted by bashtop). So somewhere in the net I read about nethogs, that this could help. So I installed it with my non-root, but sudo-grouped user.

> sudo apt install nethogs

I couldn't run it.

So I switched to the root user with

> su

It still didn't worked.
So I just wanted to check the most important thing, the ufw.

> ufw status

Output: command not found

---

So ...

1. ufw is installed
2. but it works if I execute it from the full path with

> /usr/sbin/ufw status

But I want to know also, if the incoming traffic is really blocked by default until now:

> /usr/sbin/ufw status verbose

Output: ERROR: problem running sysctl

Something is really fcked up ... I don't know why? The last thing I did 2 weeks ago was installing kuma-uptime with the kuma_install.sh
After that I didn't tried ufw. So. my $PATH seems to be not working correct- even as the root user.

I'm not an expert, but this is how my bashrc file looks like (from the root user):

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022

# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval "`dircolors`"
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
#
# Some more alias to avoid making mistakes:
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'
```

and the .profile file:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n 2> /dev/null || true
```

and this is the path to ufw:

```
ufw: /usr/sbin/ufw /etc/ufw /lib/ufw /usr/share/ufw /usr/share/man/man8/ufw.8.gz
```

and that is my echo $PATH:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
```

---

Hope this is enought and someone could help me please, you're my last hope. Otherwise I have to switch to ubuntu, maybe ubuntu behaves better. I hope, I can solve the problem with your help. It would be great, if someone could tell more or less what I have exactly to do now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an expected behavior in Debian.

`nethogs` full path is `/usr/sbin/nethogs`.

Non-root user in Debian does not have `/usr/sbin` in its default $PATH.

With command `su` you become a root, but the environment variables do not get expanded. Use either:

1. `su -` and then `nethogs`
2. `sudo su` and then `nethogs`
3. `sudo nethogs`.

More information here [Can't access some commands when logged in with non-root user (even after "su root")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553611/cant-access-some-commands-when-logged-in-with-non-root-user-even-after-su-roo).

Edit: You mention switching to Ubuntu. Ubuntu non-root user does have `/usr/sbin` in its default $PATH, so here  it might be less confusing. However, you need a root access to flawlessly run nethogs anyway.

Comment: what the heck ..!? using "su -" worked! Thank you so much <3 now I'll switch with su - to the root user. Thank you so much for the quick answer; you helped me (and maybe some other people in the future) a lot!

Comment: Might want to mention that this resulted from a change in July 2018, from the `su` in the old `shadow` source package to the `su` in the `util-linux` suite. [This bug records the history of that change.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833256). Also, [similar questions have been answered here before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460478/258991): this is just the first one I found.

Comment: For this reason I have `alias su = su -` in my bashrc.

Comment: Use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su`.

Comment: Why `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su`? Without explaining, it is just a shout from nowhere. Thanks.