# command found from "su -" but not from "su root"

Tags: debian, root, su

OS: Debian 10.10

I search to understand why the "usermod" command run when I launch with "su -" but when he is launched from "su root" the command is "bash: usermod: command not found".

Thks!

Comment: Can you perhaps edit and clarify a bit? It's really difficult to understand what you mean.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232782/117549

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`su` command without `-` keeps your existing environment, and only switches you to user without loading all of his environment variables.

`su -` will simulate user login and will not only switch you to user but also load his environment variables.

From `man su`

> ```
>    -, -l, --login
>           Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login:
>
>              o      clears all the environment variables except TERM and variables specified by --whitelist-environment
>
>              o      initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH
>
>              o      changes to the target user's home directory
>
>              o      sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the shell a login shell
> ```

In this case you probably don't load all the elements in PATH variable of root user.

Type `echo $PATH` after you do `su root` and after you do `su -` you will probably have extra folders in PATH after `su -` command.

`usermod` command should be in `/usr/sbin`, which is path only meant to be available to superuser, commands inside `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` are meant to be used for administration purposes and only run by administrative users not normal users.

you can use `type usermod` or `which usermod` and see that `usermod` is on path `/usr/sbin/usermod` and you probably won't have `/usr/sbin` in output of `echo $PATH` after `su root` but will have it inside PATH variable after `su -` command

> /sbin  Like /bin, this directory holds commands needed to boot the
> system, but which are usually not executed by normal users.
>
> /usr/sbin This directory contains program binaries for system administration which are not essential for the boot process, for
> mounting /usr, or for system repair.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `su -`, you start a shell with the root user's environment. The important part of the environment for this question is that you're getting the root user's PATH. When you leave off the `-` and just run `su root`, you retain your user's environment, and importantly, your user's PATH.