# debian root commands not working on desktop environment

Tags: shell, root, desktop-environment

I have a debian box, and after some version update or so, root commands are not recognized while being in the desktop environment; for instance `dhclient` or `reboot`.

At first, I took it as an additional security measure. But using `gparted` via an direct system access without desktop (eg using a `Ctrl-Alt-F1` login) does not make much sense.

```bsh
    $ uname -a
    Linux terbium 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-3 (2021-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
    $ cat /etc/debian_version 
    11.2
    $ su
    Password: 
    #
    root@hostname:/home/user# dhclient                  # example
    bash: dhclient: command not found
```

Is this documented behavior or just update error? or system error?
Any idea where to start or how to solve this?

[edit: To make sure I explained right: some root commands work on desktop for instance `apt`, but others work only on the desktop-free shell, eg `dhclient` or `reboot` ; and `gparted` is in limbo ...]

Comment: `/sbin` is probably missing from `$PATH`

Comment: indeed, thx for the hint ! So how come it is missing and where or how to fix it?

Comment: Check your shells config and login files

Comment: If you do `su -`, you'll get root's environment -- the hyphen specifies a login shell.

Comment: @glennjackman thx ! I was just doing `su` ... So how come I do not have the same rights in this case? [*edit*] ok, it's documented in `man su` ...

Comment: Relating (duplicate?) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232782/is-there-a-reason-i-would-not-add-usr-local-sbin-usr-sbin-sbin-to-my-path-o